# Rename an upload file on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

i'm new to ruby on rails, i would like to change the name of an image i upload
thank you

```rb
def resize_image
  resized_image = MiniMagick::Image.read(picture.image.download)
  resized_image = resized_image.combine_options do |b|
    b.resize '2760>'
    b.quality '80'
  end
  v_filename = picture.image.filename
  v_content_type = picture.image.content_type
  picture.image.purge
  picture.image.attach(io: File.open(resized_image.path), filename: v_filename, content_type: v_content_type)
end
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `v_filename = "new_name.jpeg"`?

Comment: yes it works but if I want it to be dynamic, for example replacing spaces with underscores it won't work

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Where is the dynamic part coming from, the model?

Comment: @elmd00 you can simply change the `v_filename` value before passing it to `picture.image.attach`

Comment: @Chandan if i use method like gsub i got an error like "it's not a recognized method"

Comment: @elmd00 can you share example how you are using gsub ?

Comment: @Chandan `    def resize_image
      resized_image = MiniMagick::Image.read(picture.image.download)
      resized_image = resized_image.combine_options do |b|
        b.resize '2760>'
        b.quality '80'
      end
      v_filename = picture.image.filename
      v_filename = v_filename.gsub(" ", "_")
      logger.debug "afficher moi : #{v_filename.inspect}"
      v_content_type = picture.image.content_type
      picture.image.purge
      picture.image.attach(io: File.open(resized_image.path), filename: v_filename, content_type: v_content_type)
    end`

Comment: @elmd00 can you check the class of `v_filename` is string

Comment: @Chandan ok i realize it's not a string. here is what I get `#<ActiveStorage::Filename:0x00007fb621c6d4a8 @filename="138654464_2830466637178254_8847516688544806495_o.jpg">`. now how can I access the string?

Comment: thank you I found the solution. you had to add `.to_s` to convert it to a string

Comment: @Chandan it saids that i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`picture.image.filename` is of class `ActiveStorage::Filename` so `gsub` would not work to solve the issue we need to first convert it to string using `to_s` method then we can use `gsub` to replace space`( )` with underscore`(_)`.

```rb
v_filename = v_filename.to_s.gsub(" ", "_")
```